# Debugging ArcObjects SDK 10.3 addins with ArcMap 10.4

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.4, add-in

I recently upgraded my version of ArcMap from 10.3 to 10.4.1, including all extensions, patches, etc.  I did not remove the 10.3 ArcObjects SDK, as I wanted to continue to develop 10.3 compatible addins for our organization, as we have not all upgraded yet.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 to build the addins.

I first modified MyAddinProject.csproj.user file to point to my new Desktop10.4\ArcMap.exe.

At my first attempt to debug the addin, after changing no code, ArcMap crashes shortly after splash screen and I get the following error in VS:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

I've tried modifying the Arcmap.exe.config file include the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    <!--<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>-->
    <!--<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>-->
  </startup>
```

The first and second 'supportedRuntime' lines produce the above error.  However, if I use the v2.0 supportedRuntime, ArcMap runs and the addin works, but I am unable to debug.

Is there something that should be modified to enable me to debug 10.3 addins in 10.4? Or is this not possible?

Related: [ArcGIS and .Net compatibility (Extending ArcObjects)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252581/arcgis-and-net-compatibility-extending-arcobjects)